# using of UI element in my script is giving "Expected class name but found identifier." Syntax error

Tags: applescript

I am very new to apple script, I am trying to get all the UIElements, here is my code

```
tell application "Myapp"
set visible to true
return every UI element of front window
return name of every UI element of front window
end tell
```

I got this code from [here](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3AY3zloUpd0tYJ%3Amabblog.com/blog/2010/07/applescript-tips-tricks/%20&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=nl) 
can anyone please help me to get out of this 
**Note: My OS is OS X El Capitan 10.11.1**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to ask the process of the app – which System Events knows – for that information.

```
tell application "System Events"
  tell process "Myapp"
     set visible to true
     return every UI element of front window
     -- return name of every UI element of front window
  end tell 
end tell
```

The name of the process can be different from the name of the application

Comment: Vadian this may be not the child of this question but thought of asking it here please do not mind .., I am getting "System Events got an error: Can’t get text field 1 of window 1 of process .Invalid Index" may i know why i am getting this ?

Comment: Probably there is no text field 1. Prove it by testing `exists text field 1`, the result is `true` or `false`.

Comment: There is a search textfield whose position is 1 and accessibilityRole is AXTextField

Comment: It might be inside an other UI element (box, group etc.)

Comment: ya it is, how to access such a textfield ?

Comment: You need the full reference `text field of something of window`

Comment: I dint get you, can you please quote an example

Comment: If the text field is in a box it's `text field 1 of box 1 of window 1`. However you have to figure out the exact kind and index of the intermediate UI element.

Comment: is there any way i can check how many windows are there and how many groups or box are there under it ?

Comment: Write test scripts to count the number of windows, text fields or whatever  – or use Apple's `UIElementInspector`which shows at least the UI hierarchy.